# php fopen() and fwrite() under heavy ddos attack

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, ddos, file-pointer

In normal condition , everything is ok, an I can write and create new files with `fopen()` and `fwrite()` but under "heavy" DDOS attacks , when file pointer is located at 0 , i cant write anything to file.eg. using "w" mod ,result will be a blank file , but by using "a" or "c" mod , if file not exist or be empty, nothing will be written (and just create a blank file too)  , but if file has some characters , it will writes after characters or will clear and rewrite new characters respectively.
and when DDOS stopped , everything would be Ok.
here is simple code that I'm using for test, what is the problem? Can I fix it?

I'm using php5 in ubuntu with apache and lighttpd...

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fputs($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What kind of DOS Attack ? What is the DOS attacking Web Server sever or this script (Flooding) ?

Comment: @Baba , about 700-800 ips ,each of wich every 20 seconds sending a get to one of php files but not that test script.

Comment: Are you sure those IP are unique and they are not using random proxy .... because it can easy be blocked .... if your system exceed processing or memory ... its difficult to do anything

Comment: @Baba yes , all of the GET requests are the same that is unknown And are blocking and redirecting to error 403 or 500 ,but still cause problem, and finally I blocked them by iptables...

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood the question is that you have problems running this code when there are multiple requests accessing the .php file (and thus the file you are writing to) at the same time.

Now, while it is far from being foolproof, [flock()](http://php.net/flock) is there to help with this. The basic concept is that you'd ask for a lock of the file before writing and only write to a file if you're able to get the lock to that file, like

```
$fp = fopen( $filename,"w"); // open it for WRITING ("w")
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    // do your file writes here

    // when you're done, 
    // flush your file writes to a file before unlocking
    fflush($fp);  
    // unlock the file
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    // flock() returned false, no lock obtained
    print "Could not lock $filename!\n";
}
fclose($fp);
```

You can read some more details from the [manual entry](http://php.net/flock) or [this article](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/11/0).

Comment: Thank you. but attacks are on other .php script , even at another virtual host!
by the way , I'll try and wait for next attack to test your solution...

Comment: if they are on other virtual host, there isn't probably that much you can do about it with it. It should be up to hosting provider to find solutions.

Comment: But , there is no hosting provider...I'm using ubuntu under VMware Virtual Machine. And because of DDos , main server was busy and I used that testing script on another virtual host...

Comment: ok. That sounds to me like an admin question then, rather than PHP question. You could anyway try flock if it helps any.